# I want to set $x = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, subscript

I want to get $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$.
I want to use the $x_i$ as a variable.
The following code did't work.

```
getVectorX[n_]:=Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}]
x = getVectorX[5]
```

Comment: if you need indexed variables it is better suggested to use `x[i]` instead of `Subscript[x,i]`

Comment: Thank you very much, user42582 for your advice.

Comment: $x[1] = 1$, $x = 2$, Then $x[1]$ returns $2[1]$. But I want to use $x[1]$ as a variable independent to $x$.

Comment: `Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 10]` but, as user42582 points out, indexed variables can cause problems (this is my experience).  Maybe consider `Array[x[#] &, 10]`?.

Comment: @tchappyha you need to decide what symbol you are going to use for you variables eg `x` and then you should use a *different* symbol for the the *list of variables* you are going to create; using `x` for the variables (eg `x[1]`) and the list of generated variables (eg `x = {x[1], x[2],...}`) causes infinite recursion; you could write something like eg `y = {x[1], x[2], x[3]}`.

Comment: @user1066 `Array[x[#] &, 10]` can be just `Array[x, 10]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It raises an error because `x` appears at both the right- and left-hand sides of your last expression. Try renaming one side instead, for example

```
xVec = getVectorX[5]
```

BTW, `Indexed` can replace `Subscript` here.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for the subscripted variable to be a symbol. Just use a string instead, and you won't have to worry about recursion errors because the subscripted variable is the same as the variable on the LHS:

```
getVectorX[n_] := Table[Subscript["x", i], {i, 1, n}]
x = getVectorX[5];
x //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\text{x}_1,\text{x}_2,\text{x}_3,\text{x}_4,\text{x}_5\right\}$